# Find Time Series Values of Cell AND Cell Location in R

Tags: r, set, boolean

I'm trying to pull up two things: values in one cell that are  > / < / = to values in another cell, and the corresponding dates to the cell. In this case it is >.

My data - res - is:

```
head(res)
GMT
              NYSELOSS     ES99
1993-12-16 -0.28136694 1.743147
1993-12-17 -0.63817553 1.719892
1993-12-20  0.07743844 1.758305
1993-12-21  0.17491580 1.742691
1993-12-22 -0.39203213 1.719068
1993-12-23 -0.13143421 1.723541


 tail(res)
 GMT
              NYSELOSS     ES99
  2005-11-04  0.3623103 3.000793
  2005-11-07 -0.1578494 2.928393
  2005-11-08  0.3957594 2.839604
  2005-11-09 -0.1503598 2.780169
  2005-11-10 -0.3877294 2.698658
  2005-11-11 -0.4144052 2.634240
```

I can pull up the values with this string of code:

```
res[(res$NYSELOSS >= res$ES99)]

[1] 2.259965 3.015331 6.791045 5.274660 4.701324 1.648440 2.699520 4.060133 4.418048 4.104483
```

But I cannot pull up the corresponding dates.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the data:

```
dput(head(res))
new("timeSeries"
    , .Data = structure(c(-0.281366940350214, -0.638175532646112, 0.0774384430632047, 
0.174915802081443, -0.392032128912856, -0.131434207552861, 1.74314672137931, 
1.71989198272187, 1.75830475778356, 1.74269091505136, 1.71906771494426, 
1.72354094272865), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("NYSELOSS", 
"ES99")))
    , units = c("NYSELOSS", "ES99")
    , positions = c(7.56e+08, 756086400, 756345600, 756432000, 756518400, 756604800
)
    , format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    , FinCenter = "GMT"
    , recordIDs = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")
    , title = "Time Series Object"
    , documentation = "Tue Jun  3 15:02:41 2014"
)
```

**Update2**

Still having issues :/

```
subset(res, res$NYSELOSS >= res$ES99, select = "GMT")
 [1] 2.259965 3.015331 6.791045 5.274660 4.701324 1.648440 2.699520 4.060133 4.418048 4.104483
```

Comment: Also tried: 'subset(res, res$NYSELOSS >= res$ES99)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you're interested in are the row names of your data set. You should be able to get those by using `row.names`, like so for example:

```
row.names(subset(res, NYSELOSS >= ES99))
```

UPDATE: the object is a `timeSeries` object from the package `timeSeries` and `subset` is not implemented for this kind of object (unlike `head` and `tail` which are implemented). In order to subset, you have to wrap `as.data.frame` around the object:

```
row.names(subset(as.data.frame(res), NYSELOSS >= ES99))
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hum...maybe it is something wrong with my code.                       '> row.names(subset(res, NYSELOSS >= ES99))
Error in subset.default(res, NYSELOSS >= ES99) : object 'ES99' not found'

Comment: Could you provide a couple of lines from your data? that'll make it easy to tell, use `dput(head(res))`

Comment: Updated. But, your solution returns all 6002 values in res, rather than the subset :/

Comment: Ah, I see, you have a `timeSeries` object, not a `data.frame`, that explains why it failed trying to call `subset.default`. You'll need to wrap it with as.data.frame to use this approach, I'll update the answer in a sec.